# Terraform - deploying in multiple accounts

Tags: terraform

Im currently working with Multiple AWS accounts within an organization. I have multiple providers setup with assume role.

Is there a way to have resources roll through all the providers to ensure everything is installed that I've defined in a Terraform module? I'm trying to avoid having a resource per provider and have one resource that would use each provider.

Hope someone can help with this or has a use case like this.

TIA

Comment: From what you're asking I think the answer here is no but if you could share a [mcve] of what you've currently got and what you would like to do instead then someone might be able to suggest a better way of structuring things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible to have just one resource block using multiple providers. The best way to do is to have different folders for different accounts in organisation. Each folder having its main.tf with the same resource block/s (as in your case), and different provider.tf. Inside your main you can call the required modules.

For your case, it might seem as a lot of redundant code but this is the best option. Refer the project structure below to get an idea.

```
|   Project Directory
|   
+---dev
|   |   main.tf
|   |   param.tfvars
|   |   provider.tf
|   |   terraform.tfstate
|   |   terraform.tfstate.backup
|   |   variables.tf
|   |   
+---modules
|   +---internetgateway
|   |       main.tf
|   |       outputs.tf
|   |       variables.tf
|   |       
|   +---nat
|   |       main.tf
|   |       outputs.tf
|   |       variables.tf
|   |       
+---prod
|   |   main.tf
|   |   param.tfvars
|   |   provider.tf
|   |   terraform.tfstate
|   |   terraform.tfstate.backup
|   |   variables.tf
|   |
+---test
|   |   main.tf
|   |   param.tfvars
|   |   provider.tf
|   |   terraform.tfstate
|   |   terraform.tfstate.backup
|   |   variables.tf
```

Comment: It would be more useful if you shared your directory layout using something like `tree` instead of a screenshot.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I know it looks bad but I couldn't figure out how to draw a tree. It would be nice if you can edit the answer.

Comment: There is a util called `tree` that will do it for you given your directory structure. Otherwise I need to create your directory structure locally and then run `tree`.

Comment: @ShivRajawat So you didn't create a module for each? You have a TFstate for each sub folder? Could you explain this a bit further? I've started to do this work based on your tree above, but im managing all in one TFstate, wondering if you did it the way you did for a specific reason.

Comment: Since each environment (dev, pre-prod, prod etc.) have a different configuration, it is advisable to use seperate state files for each of them, so that you can easily perform apply/destroy for a particular environment without affecting others. Though it is not  recommended to store state locally (as I did), preferably use a single backend (eg. S3) and have seperate files for every environment.

Comment: Use modules for resources and use 'count' inside modules. Call them from each environment/sub-folder with  proper value of count, which will vary across environment as per their requirement.

Comment: Thanks thats great info. One other question, how do you maintain a state file in each subfolder? Whenever i try to save a remote state for each subfolder , its only taking the backend i specified in my root  main.tf.

Comment: Please elaborate your problem, preferably ask a new question so that others facing the same issue can also benefit from it.

Comment: @hhh0505 - Please make an habit of accepting and up-voting the answer if it worked for you. It will help others. Thanks!